# JPA (Hibernate) XA Datasource execute Stored Procedure in Transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, jboss, xa

I'm using JBoss 6, JPA (Hibernate) on Sql Server 2005 using XA Transactions.
I am able to run queries and stored procedures, but I am trying to run a certain stored procedure in it's own transaction (sort of).
Meaning if the stored procedure fails or returns a error, changes made by the stored procedure should be rolledback, but not the changes done by other queries such as entityManager.persist()

I've tried BEGIN TRANSACTION, ROLLBACK etc... in the stored procedure itself, but I get a JDBC error that the transaction does not exist.

How can I accomplish this? 
Running the stored procedure in it's own transaction? (not sure how)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try SAVEPOINTS instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx

Comment: IOW run a global transaction, then inside your procedure first make a savepoint and conditionally rollback to that savepoint before you return from a procedure

Comment: And also don't forget to flush just BEFORE you call your procudure, I don't think Hibernate is able to deduce it for you

Comment: @tair it doesn't work with SAVEPOINTS, I get "Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction."

Comment: Did you enable nested TX support in Arjuna (JTS implementation in JBoss)? It is off by default.

Comment: Didn't work either, but my problem is solved, answered my own  question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, this method executing the stored procedure was a sub method in a EJB, but it was not part of the business interface, Apparently new transactions are not created in this case (even with REQUIRES_NEW), correct me if I'm wrong.

I ended up moving the method to a different EJB and annotating the method with
`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` and getting the SessionContext via

```
@Resource
protected SessionContext ctx;
```

and doing `ctx.setRollbackOnly();` when I needed to rollback the stored procedure's changes without rolling back the outer transactions changes.

This works fine for me, but if I got anything wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: This way you end up having independent transaction instead of nested, because rolling back the outer TX won't rollback the inner one. So your solution is correct as long as above is acceptable...